# Above the Fold Content

Tags: php

I just wanted to find out is (Only about 64% of the final above-the-fold content could be rendered with the full HTML response.) Is that good or bad? If so, please could you let me know how to bring it down or boost it up.

I am running my site through google page speed insights and I need to get it 100/100 on mobile. Also I would like opinions on google page insights, is it accurate? I was using GT Metrix and I found that I had no major problems on my sites, but with Google, there are always issues.

Thanks and appreciate the help!

Comment: How is this related to PHP? Probably, you should add some more precise tags

Comment: I would personnally take page speed insights as an abstract ideal, not a test where you need/can score maximum (at least reasonably, considering the time you'd have to involve for it and the not so much substancial gain you would have from it). Nobody "needs" to get 100/100 on mobile. As a test, try it with your favorite well-known websites, to have a comparison

Comment: Thanks guys, but how do I sort out the above the fold content? Sorry I am new to code, so this is all so confusing to me